# Change a SQL server query to equivalent in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-server-2005

I have this query which works in SQL server:

```
Convert(datetime, [ChangedDate]) >= DATEADD(DAY, -3, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

I want to make it work in Android SQLite database.

As far as I understood I need to use something like: `date('now','+14 day')` instead of `DATEADD`, but it gives me an error on `datetime` (it could be here Convert(datetime,...) in sqlite.

Can you modify this query in order to make it works on SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not have a `date` data type.  So you're not required to use `convert` or `cast`.  A query like this would work:

```
select  *
from    table1
where   col1 < datetime('now', '-3 days')
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3d023/2/0)

For more details, see the [SQLite manual](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> 1.2 Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
>
> **REAL** as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
>
> **INTEGER**
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. Let me to check it out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to SQL Fiddle! It's helping me convert all my SQLite statements into MS SQL statements.